# Unable to open Infowindow on Map Pan

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the code below to link an HTML list to markers on a map. When I click on the markers, the InfoWindow opens without any problem. However when I click on the list item, although the map pans correctly and centres on the appropriate marker, I cannot get the InfoWindow to open at the same time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Map My Finds - All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mylocations.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <style>
    div#locationslist div{     
    cursor:pointer; } 
    </style>    

        <div id="map"></div> 
        <div id="locationslist"></div> 

        <body onload="showLocations()"> 

            <script type="text/javascript"> 

                var map; 
                var gmarkers = new Array();
                var locationslist;

                function showLocations() { 
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
                zoom:6, 
                mapTypeId: 'terrain' 
                }); 
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 

                // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
                downloadUrl("loadmylocations.php", function(data) { 
                var xml = data.responseXML; 
                gmarkers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
                for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) { 
                var locationname = gmarkers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
                var address = gmarkers[i].getAttribute("address"); 
                var locationid = gmarkers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
                parseFloat(gmarkers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
                parseFloat(gmarkers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon"))); 
                var html = "<b>" + locationname + "</b> <br/>" + address; 
                bounds.extend(point);  
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                map: map, 
                position: point, 
                locationid: locationid 
                }); 
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);  
                locationslist += "<div onclick=scrollToMarker(" + i + ")>"+locationname+"</div>"; 
                }        
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); 
                map.fitBounds(bounds);  
                //display company data in html 
                document.getElementById("locationslist").innerHTML = locationslist; 
                });  
                } 

                function scrollToMarker(index) {  
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
                parseFloat(gmarkers[index].getAttribute("osgb36lat")),  
                parseFloat(gmarkers[index].getAttribute("osgb36lon")) 
                ); 
                map.panTo(point);  
                } 

                function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
                infoWindow.setContent(html); 
                infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
                }); 
                } 

                function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
                var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
                new XMLHttpRequest; 

                request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                if (request.readyState == 4) { 
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
                callback(request, request.status); 
                } 
                }; 

                request.open('GET', url, true); 
                request.send(null); 
                } 
                function doNothing(){ 
                } 

                </script> 
                </head>    
                </body> 
                </html>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Map My Finds - All Locations</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script> 
<style> 
    div#locationslist div{cursor:pointer; }  
    html { height: 100% } 
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 } 
    #map { height: 70%; width:70% } 
</style>     

<script type="text/javascript">  
var map;  
var gmarkers = []; 
var locationslist = ""; 
var arrMarkers = [];    // add our markers to this array 

function showLocations() {  
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {  
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007),  
        zoom:6,  
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
    });  
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;  
      downloadUrl("loadmylocations.php", function(data) { 
                var xml = data.responseXML; 
                gmarkers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {  
        var locationname = gmarkers[i]["locationname"];  
        var address = gmarkers[i]["address"];  
        //var locationid = gmarkers[i]["locationid"];  
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(  
            parseFloat(gmarkers[i]["osgb36lat"]),  
            parseFloat(gmarkers[i]["osgb36lon"]));  
        var html = "<b>" + locationname + "</b> <br/>" + address;  
        bounds.extend(point);   
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,  
            position: point 
        });  

        arrMarkers.push(marker); 

        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);   
        locationslist += "<div onclick=scrollToMarker(" + i + ")>"+locationname+"</div>";  
    } 
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());  
    map.fitBounds(bounds);   
    //display company data in html  
    document.getElementById("locationslist").innerHTML = locationslist;  
 });  
                }  

function scrollToMarker(index) {   
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(  
        parseFloat(gmarkers[index]["osgb36lat"]),   
        parseFloat(gmarkers[index]["osgb36lon"])  
    );  

    map.panTo(point);  

    google.maps.event.trigger(arrMarkers[index], 'click');  
}  

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
        infoWindow.setContent(html);  
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);  
    });  
}  
</script>  
</head> 
<body onload="showLocations()">  
    <div id="map"></div>  
    <div id="locationslist"></div>   
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've binded the click event on the marker to open an infowindow. What you want to do is trigger that click, i.e. as if the user had done it themselves.

Something like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
```

The hard part will be for you to identify which marker the click event is firing on.  Suggest you have an array of all your markers.  At the same time as you call scrollToMarker, also do this trigger, and pass through the index parameter too, to identify which marker in your array you're wanting to 'click'

Update: ok, here's a working example of what I mean.  I've removed your Ajax request part and put in some dummy marker data, but it should be simple enough for you to figure out how to integrate into your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Map My Finds - All Locations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mylocations.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<style>
    div#locationslist div{cursor:pointer; } 
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map { height: 70%; width:70% }
</style>    

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map; 
var gmarkers = [];
var locationslist = "";
var arrMarkers = [];    // add our markers to this array

function showLocations() { 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
        zoom:6, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }); 
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 

    gmarkers = [
        {locationname: "One", address: "blah", osgb36lat: "51.482238", osgb36lon: "0.001581"},
        {locationname: "Two", address: "blahblah", osgb36lat: "51.473364", osgb36lon: "0.011966"},
        {locationname: "Three", address: "blahblahblah", osgb36lat: "51.471974", osgb36lon: "-0.000651"},
        {locationname: "Four", address: "blahblahblahblah", osgb36lat: "51.472108", osgb36lon: "-0.002196"},
        {locationname: "Five", address: "foobar", osgb36lat: "51.474995", osgb36lon: "-0.003827"},
    ];

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) { 
        var locationname = gmarkers[i]["locationname"]; 
        var address = gmarkers[i]["address"]; 
        //var locationid = gmarkers[i]["locationid"]; 
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(gmarkers[i]["osgb36lat"]), 
            parseFloat(gmarkers[i]["osgb36lon"])
        ); 
        var html = "<b>" + locationname + "</b> <br/>" + address; 
        bounds.extend(point);  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            map: map, 
            position: point
        }); 

        arrMarkers.push(marker);

        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);  
        locationslist += "<div onclick=scrollToMarker(" + i + ")>"+locationname+"</div>"; 
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); 
    map.fitBounds(bounds);  
    //display company data in html 
    document.getElementById("locationslist").innerHTML = locationslist; 
} 

function scrollToMarker(index) {  
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
        parseFloat(gmarkers[index]["osgb36lat"]),  
        parseFloat(gmarkers[index]["osgb36lon"]) 
    ); 

    map.panTo(point); 

    google.maps.event.trigger(arrMarkers[index], 'click'); 
} 

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
    }); 
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="showLocations()"> 
    <div id="map"></div> 
    <div id="locationslist"></div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the help. Forgive me I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to this, but is this right direction I should be taking?
       map.panTo(point);
       function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
       google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers, 'click', function()  { 
       infoWindow.setContent(html); 
       infoWindow.open(map, gmarkers); 
       }); 
       } 
       } 

Kind regards. Chris

Comment: Not exactly; I'll see if I can post up a working example later

Comment: Hi Duncan, sincere thanks for the code.I'm being really dense here, but I can't get this to work.I've tried to include the link to my php file, but get the following error object expected line 28 character 7 pointing to this line:  
downloadUrl("loadmylocations.php", function(data) { 
I've updated my original post showing my revised code.I just wondered whether you could possibly please have a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong. I think it may be because I'm trying to 'get the attribute' for each marker which isn't there. But I could very well be wrong. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: The problem now is you need to get rid of my way of referencing gmarkers[i]["locationname"] etc, and go back to gmarkers[i].getAttribute("locationname")

Comment: Hi Duncan, many thanks for your continued help, and patience! I've made the changes as you suggested, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error at the same line. Rather than me making things more complicated and adding another set of amended code, please find a link to my page. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/alllocationssidebar3.html Could you possibly please take a look at this and let me know what I'm doing wrong. I'm sorry to keep pestering you with this. Sincere thanks and regards. Chris

Comment: You need to add back in the downloadUrl and doNothing functions

Comment: Hi many thanks for bearing with me it's grately appreciated.Except for a brain, I really must be missing something.I've added the code that was missing, the list & map render but I'm getting the error: 'object expected at line 1 character 1' I've referred back to the original script & except for the obvious code changes I can't find why the error is occuring. I think you can probably tell, but I'm fairly new in learning to write Javascript, but for errors such as this is there a way of trying to highlighting these with programming tools or is it just a question of practice? Kind regards. Chris

Comment: One tool that's useful is jslint.com (although very strict, it can pick up some errors in your code).  Also Firebug and console.log() are your friends.

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance on the tools, I'll start to learn how to use those. Could you possibly help me please though with an issue I still have with my script. Everything renders as it should, but when I click on any of the HTML list entries I'm still receiving the error: 'object expected at line 1 character 1'. I've been looking at this since yesterday and I can't find any issue. I have used 'JS Lint' within 'JS Fiddle' and the code is shown as being valid. Many thnaks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi Duncan, since my last post I've been working on this and I've got the code to work. I just wanted to say thnak you for all your help, guidance and patience, it is gratefully appreciated. Kind regards. Chris